# Metrics responsed in random order on querying CrUX Report API

Tags: chrome-ux-report

I queries to CrUX Report API, as dev docs [show](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-user-experience-report/api/guides/getting-started).

Instead of `origin` I use `url` to get data for certain URLs, so my query looks like:

```
curl https://chromeuxreport.googleapis.com/v1/records:queryRecord?key=API_KEY \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json'   --data '{"url":"https://www.spiegel.de/schlagzeilen/"}'
```

I do this one by one for different urls.

My problem: responses are coming in different order: for the first query `CLS` comes as first metric, for the second query - `FID` and so on.

This issue doesn't depend on the kind I run queries: cURL in terminal, by Postman, or by Google App script in Google Sheets.

I tried to setup an explicit metrics order in the request, like

```
curl https://chromeuxreport.googleapis.com/v1/records:queryRecord?key=API_KEY \
      --header 'Content-Type: application/json'   --data '{"url":"https://www.spiegel.de/schlagzeilen/","metrics":["cumulative_layout_shift","first_contentful_paint","first_input_delay","largest_contentful_paint"]}'
```

but responses come still in random order.

**Q**: is there a possibility to force a metrics order in the response I wish to have?

Answer (score 0):

While the `metrics` input parameter does allow you to list the metrics that get output in the results, it doesn't control the ordering of the metrics. There is no other input mechanism to enforce a particular metric ordering.

That said, the `metrics` response is a JSON object, which is an inherently unordered data structure. The ordering of the object keys may affect how the object is iterated, for example `Object.fromEntries(response.record.metrics)` will iterate over the metrics in the order they appear.

If the order is critical to your application, I would recommend deterministically looping through a constant array of metric IDs rather than iterating over the object keys. For example:

```js
const METRICS = ['first_contentful_paint', 'largest_contentful_paint', 'first_input_delay', 'cumulative_layout_shift'];
const cruxData = METRICS.map(metric => response.record[metric]);
```

I see you're using cURL to issue the requests, so you can adapt this strategy to whichever programming language you use to parse the results.

Comment: Could you advice me how to adjust the cURL structure to get the ordered response? Doing this with `"metrics":["cumulative_layout_shift","first_contentful_paint","first_input_delay","largest_contentful_paint"]` didn't help me...

Comment: The `metrics` parameter doesn't control the ordering of the results, so to enforce the order you would need to handle that in your application code., similar to the example I gave.